# check event is raised twice after routing Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with a mat checkbox event in my Angular app:

The event is used to filter a list. When the component is loaded for the first time, the filter works as expected, but after routing to another component, and returning back to the previous component, this filter is no more working.

After some researches, I discovered that, after the routing, the check event is raised twice for each click, which causes the filter not to work.

html file

```
<mat-checkbox (change)="onTeamFiletr($event)" value="equipe,{{equipe.id}}" 
[checked]="isSelectedToFilter(equipe.id)">
```

.ts file

```
onTeamFiletr($event){
this.sharedService.triggerSomeEvent($event)
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing an `unsubscribe()` from a `Subscription` of an `Observable` in `ngOnDestroy()`.

It sounds like it could be that, if you are getting the event twice when you go back to the page. I can't know without see the rest of your code.

Comment: Yes you're right, I forgot to `unsubscribe()` from a `Subscription`.